# Request number of jobs submitted with Torque

Tags: torque

How would one request to see the total number of jobs that a user has currently submitted?  This could be running jobs, queued jobs, or both.  Preferably, I would like to see all of the jobs that I have currently (running and queued).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick oneliner that should do the job.

```
qstat -u username | awk '{if (NR > 5) print}' | wc -l
```

The number of lines to skip at the top depends on your flavor of PBS. It is 5 on torque and PBS Professional if only one server is available.

Comment: Excellent!  As a note, one can put the `-t` flag in there to list all jobs if you have arrays jobs submitted.